# Find records with specific date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

1. I want to select all records that are not in format yyyy-mm-dd. Datatype of column is `varchar`.
2. Update the records in step 1 with the correct format(yyyy-mm-dd).

I have tried filtering with function: `IsDate()` but got no success.

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE #tempdate (dateCol varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #tempdate VALUES 
('2019-05-13 16:55:47:284'),
('2019-04-05 14:08:10.060'),
('6/19/2018 12:35:53 PM'),
('2019-05-13');
```

Comment: Don't store dates as varchar and you wouldn't have this problem. You can use LIKE against a pattern to find which ones arent yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. *You can't* find out the format from a string - what does `04/07/2019` mean? April 7th or June 4th?

Comment: In any case, 3 of those strings use the ISO8601 format and can easily be converted to proper date values. Only the 3rd item causes problems. Switch to a proper date type like `datetime2` to avoid such problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 04/07/2019 means mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @sgharsh no it does't. Today is 21/10/2019 in most European countries (if not most countries in the world). Just *don't* use such localized formats. Those that differ use different separators. `MM/dd` is US-specific. Just *don't* use localized strings for dates. Either use the proper type (eg `date` or `datetime2`) or use an unambiguous string format like ISO8601 or the unseparated date format YYYYMMDD

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks for the guidance. I will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `try_cast()`

```
select try_cast(datecol as date)
```

Comment: A simple `CAST()` is aware of your system's culture. Date and time values should always be treated with `CONVERT()` using the third parameter to avoid unexpected results or failures...

Comment: Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a1cf06477e4de2e1661cc6282aa8990.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Your fiddle returns a valid date with `set language english;` but returns NULL with `set language german;`. Living in a german speaking country I'm used to think about culture whenever I I've to deal with string-formatted date or time values. I think it is rather dangerous to rely on `cast()` or `try_cast()`...

Comment: @Shnugo . . . I think it is more dangerous to store dates as strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's why my own answer starts exactly with this hint 

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
update #tempdate set datecol=format(cast(dateCol as date),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: The simple `cast(dateCol as date)` will be culture aware and therefore return differently on different machines. Date and time values should always be treated with `CONVERT()` using the third paramter to avoid unexpected results or failures...

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
SELECT * FROM #tempdate 
WHERE ISDATE(dateCol)= 1 AND CHARINDEX('-',dateCol) = 5
```

2.

```
UPDATE #tempdate
SET datecol = CONVERT(DATETIME,datecol,102)
WHERE ISDATE(dateCol)= 1 

SELECT * FROM #tempdate
```

Comment: `ISDATE()`, as well as a simple `CAST()` are aware of your system's culture. Date and time values should always be treated with `CONVERT()` using the third parameter to avoid unexpected results or failures...

Answer (score 0):

The most important answer was given by EzLo in a comment above: Do not store date/time values in a string format.

A native date/time type is stored in a non-readable, binary pattern. Any action will be faster and secure against culture dependency.

The readable format is something for the output only and should be done in exports or within your presentation layer.

If you have to stick with this (or if this is your attempt to clean and transform your data to a correct format), I'd suggest one of those:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tempdate
```

--either use a text base pattern

```
WHERE LEFT(dateCol,10) NOT LIKE '[1,2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0,1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]';
```

--or use a fixed conversion format (here I use 126 for ISO8601)

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,dateCol,126) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the below.

```
update #tempdate set datecol=Convert(char(10),convert(datetime,datecol,120),126)
```

Please let me know

Thanks